# Creating a view with columns based on where clauses

Tags: sql

With the help of SO I've been picking up a little SQL today.

I created a view like this:

```
CREATE VIEW  RDMAVWSANDBOX.VwNIM001usersAndDlCount AS
SELECT VwNIMEventFct.NIM_USER_ID, COUNT(VwNIMEventFct.NIM_EVENT_TYPE_ID) AS DownloadCount
FROM RDMAVWSANDBOX.VwNIMEventFct
WHERE NIM_EVENT_TYPE_ID = 884
GROUP BY NIM_USER_ID
```

And that works fine.

Except, the column `NIM_EVENT_TYPE_ID` has say 5 variations: `880,881,883,884,885`.

In the query above I created a view with the count of 884. The results look like:

```
NIM_USER_ID | DownloadCount
```

Because 884 represents a download.

But if I wanted to create a view like this:

```
NIM_USER_ID | DownloadCount(based884) | SomeOtherEventCount(based880) | SomeOtherEventCount1(Bases 883) | Etc
```

Is there a way to do that and create it all in the one view?

Put another way, I'd like the count of each instance of 880-885 for each `NIM_USER_ID`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    CREATE VIEW  RDMAVWSANDBOX.VwNIM001usersAndDlCount AS
    SELECT VwNIMEventFct.NIM_USER_ID
   ,SUM(CASE WHEN NIM_EVENT_TYPE_ID = 884 then 1 else 0 end) AS DownloadCount
   ,SUM(CASE WHEN NIM_EVENT_TYPE_ID = 885 then 1 else 0 end) AS Something
   ,SUM(CASE WHEN NIM_EVENT_TYPE_ID = 886 then 1 else 0 end) AS Something
   ,SUM(CASE WHEN NIM_EVENT_TYPE_ID = 887 then 1 else 0 end) AS Something
    FROM RDMAVWSANDBOX.VwNIMEventFct
    GROUP BY NIM_USER_ID
```

How about this one?

Comment: Thank you very much. That worked. I'll need to get my head around "CASE WHEN" now though

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this is what you want?

```
CREATE VIEW  RDMAVWSANDBOX.VwNIM001usersAndDlCount AS
  SELECT 
     VwNIMEventFct.NIM_USER_ID,
     SUM(CASE WHEN NIM_EVENT_TYPE_ID = 880 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [Count for 880],
     SUM(CASE WHEN NIM_EVENT_TYPE_ID = 881 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [Count for 881],
     SUM(CASE WHEN NIM_EVENT_TYPE_ID = 882 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [Count for 882],
     SUM(CASE WHEN NIM_EVENT_TYPE_ID = 883 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [Count for 883],
     SUM(CASE WHEN NIM_EVENT_TYPE_ID = 884 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [Count for 884],
     SUM(CASE WHEN NIM_EVENT_TYPE_ID = 885 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [Count for 885]
  FROM RDMAVWSANDBOX.VwNIMEventFct
  GROUP BY NIM_USER_ID
```

You would have to change the column names and the displayed order to suit your needs, but the example should give you an idea.

Comment: Thanks for the helpful info. Only accepted other answer since they got their first. It works and that's great.

Comment: @DougFirr Yeah, I was a bit slow. The answers are pretty much identical so you should accept the oldest :)